I created a chat using Firebase Stream Builder in Flutter, but the app crashed because there was too much data
I made a chat using Firebase Stream Builder on Flutter, but as the number of chats increases, the number of data calls up and it goes down. The future builder has data pageing, but the stream does not have pageing, so how is everyone else making it?
Is there any other way other than limit?
App.db
 .collection("talk_content")
        .where("roomId", isEqualTo: roomId)
        .where("enable", isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy("regdate", descending: true)
        .withConverter(fromFirestore: (data, _) {
      return ChatModel.fromJson(data.data()!, data.id);
    }, toFirestore: (josn, _) {
      return josn.toJson();
    }).snapshots();


When you open the chat fetch the latest 30-40 msg using get() not snapshot. And after that set stream subscription for new msg after the last from the get().

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to SO. If the question is "How do I paginate" - there are dozens, if not hundreds of questions and answers here on SO regarding pagination - and it's also covered in the documentation. Take a look and see if any of those helps.
